# LWJGL HUD in a 2D Game

Tags: java, camera, lwjgl, orthographic

So I am programming a 2D game in Java with LWJGL. I have my ortho camera in my gameloop and set it on the position I want to see. Now when I want to draw a HUD to show my money etc, I can either give it an absolute coordinate, so that it is part of my map and I can scroll away from my HUD (that definitely doesn't make sense for HUDs), or I can add my HUD vector to my cameras bottom-left Vector. Problem with that last solution is, that if I move my camera, my HUD does not perfectly update and you see it chasing its actual position.

So my question is:
Is there any way I can set a fixed position relative to my screen in a second 'layer'?
I've seen some people who only use gltranslate to move camera, but I guess it could be much work to change it now, so I'd like to keep my ortho camera.

**edit:**

This is what my Graphicsloop looks like and it still does not work properly:

```
private void updateRunning() {
  cam.update();
  drawEntities();
  drawHud();
  cursor.draw();
}
```

Comment: You basically want a 2D stuff over a 3D scene?

Comment: I need a 2D Hud in a 2D Game. Nothing to do with 3D

Comment: Where are you updating your player position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can add my HUD vector to my cameras bottom-left Vector. Problem with that last solution is, that if I move my camera, my HUD does not perfectly update and you see it chasing its actual position.

That's not what should happen. What's likely happening is you have something like this:

```
gameLoop() {
    update();
    drawPlayer();
    drawHud();
    updateCamera();
}
```

However, you need to update the camera *before* drawing anything (or even before updating).

```
gameLoop() {
    update();
    updateCamera();
    drawPlayer();
    drawHud();
}
```

To draw the HUD on top of other objects, just render it after.

```
drawBackground();
drawPlayer();
drawHUD();
```

Comment: I dont need help to draw a 2D Hud in a 3D Game. I need to know how I can draw one in a 2D Game itself

Comment: Does the camera follow your player?

Comment: Okay I solved it. I swapped cam.update(); with drawEntities();, because I thought he might take too much time to draw them. Only thing is, that Im still updating camera after drawing Entities. But as its a 2D game I dont know how I could use z axis to draw Hud above Entities then. And no it doesnt follow Player, because I dont have one

Comment: It's just the order you render it in.

Comment: Exactly. I need to draw entities first then, but I need to draw my hud immediately after I update my camera

Comment: You update all your entities, update your camera, then render all your entities, then render your HUD.

Comment: rendering entities takes too much time. I have a delay then. Updating entities etc happens in a different thread

Comment: Thanks for that advice. Made me think of having not even one calculation in my rendercode. Works like a charm now, thanks a lot.

Comment: @besplash Glad I could help! Update and render usually are seperated.